# Access SysCmd function not working as expected for some action values

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, statusbar

I've read the [relevant historical material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844653/how-to-show-progress-on-status-bar-when-running-code-not-queries?lq=1%20%22title) and this is not the same issue others have had. Adding `DoEvents` has no effect.

#### First Problem

`RetVal = SysCmd(4, "Here's an Update!")` clears the status bar text and meter, instead of updating the text. I have tested this in a sub and in the immediate window using `?SysCmd(4, "some text")`.

#### Second Problem

More confusing is that `SysCmd(3)` and `SysCmd(5)` **both** entirely remove the status bar, text and meter. `SysCmd(3)` is described in [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/103404):

> When the  argument is 3, the progress meter is removed from the status bar.

For `SysCmd(5)` on [another page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105511):

> When the action argument is 5, the status bar text set by the previous SysCmd() function is removed.

Contrary to these descriptions, the entire status bar is removed.

I even tried testing [the suggested sub from Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105511):

```
Function StatusBar ()
     Dim RetVal As Variant
     RetVal = SysCmd(4, "The rain in Spain falls mainly ...")
     MsgBox "Press OK when you are ready to finish!"
     RetVal = SysCmd(5)
  End Function
```

Testing this resulted in only the message box.

#### Everything Else Works

Everything else works fine, as far as I can tell. These work as expected:

```
RetVal = SysCmd(1, "Beginning Queries...", 10) 'adds the status bar 
RetVal = SysCmd(2,1) 'moves the meter
```

Adding the constant names (i.e. `acSysCmdSetStatus`) does not seem to have any effect in Access 2010 (since this is Access VBA, not VBS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I had was all about a bad misconception. The `SysCmd` method does [a lot of things](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214117%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and it's a little overwhelming.

At the very bottom of Access, we have the status bar. The text on the very **bottom left** is the [Status Bar Text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/105511). This is controlled via the `acSysCmdSetStatus` (value of `4`) and `acSysCmdClearStatus` (value of `5`).

This text cannot be used at the same time as the [Status Bar Progress Meter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/103404), which is on the **bottom right** of the status bar. It has its own text.

The misconception above is the idea that the status bar text actions change the text of the status bar progress meter. And they don't.

For reference on `SysCmd` action values, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225984%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell. Your code works nicely here in A2013, so does a reduced version:

```
Public Function StatusBar()
    SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, "The rain in Spain falls mainly ..."
    MsgBox "Press OK when you are ready to finish!"
    SysCmd acSysCmdClearStatus
End Function
```

The status text is displayed, the messagebox pops forward, the statusbar is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
        SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "Processing " & CStr(rstNewJobsToPopulate.RecordCount) & " PL Jobs...", rstNewJobsToPopulate.RecordCount
        Progress_Amount = 0
        
        With rstNewJobsToPopulate
            While Not .EOF
                ' Update the progress meter.
                SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, Progress_Amount
                If Not (CBool(Progress_Amount Mod 10)) Then
                    SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "Processing " & CStr(Progress_Amount) & " Of " & CStr(rstNewJobsToPopulate.RecordCount) & " PL Jobs...", rstNewJobsToPopulate.RecordCount
                    SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, Progress_Amount
                End If
                varx = Get_Website_Job_Detail(![URL], strPL_Table_Name)
                .MoveNext
                Progress_Amount = Progress_Amount + 1
            Wend
        End With
```